# C: Additional chars in char array when using scanf to put "string" in char array,

Tags: c, arrays, char, scanf

I am experiencing an issue regarding the comparison of strings (arrays of chars). 
The code below is not my program but rather a simulation of what I am doing.
I have a struct, which stores an item's name. 
I later have a user search for items using an input name, 
which matches a struct Item's instance name (like Xenon) with that user input. 
However, the input string contains gibberish, which I will show. 
I have added '\0' to the end of my char, so this should not be an issue, 
unless I am doing that incorrectly. 

To be more clear,
A user enters, "Xenon", so we find the instance of struct Item that
has "Xenon" as its name value.

```
// Section #A
// I store structs in this dynamically allocated array. 
// Later, users can access item instances, if needed.
struct Item *struct_arr = malloc( sizeof(struct Item)*SIZE );

struct Item
{
        char name[16];
        float price;
        int quantity;
        int id_num;
};
struct Item item1;
strcpy(item1.name, "Xenon"); // i explicitly set this instance 
item1.price = 125; 
item1.quantity = 2;
item1.id_num = 1;
struct_arr[0] = item1;

// Section #B
char name[16]; // also tried 17
name[16] = '\0'; // or 17, tried 17
scanf("%s", name); // assume I enter, "Xenon"
// res outputs 2
int res = strcmp(item1.name, name); // They are not the same, though when printed, "Xenon" and "Xenon"


// THE ISSUE IS BELOW : THE SOLUTION IS SET strcmp == 0
for (int i=0; i < SIZE; i++) {
           if (strcmp(struct_arr[i].name, name)) { // strcmp(struct_arr[i].name, name) == 0

                   int res = strcmp(struct_arr[i].name, name); * #A                   

                   break;
           }

 }
// i then proceeded to gdb to see what was going on. Read on
```

In gdb, I step to the point in my program where 
I am using the user's input (stored in char array "name") 
to select the correct struct Item instance.

Gdb gives results like the following: 
print name 
"Xenon\000\000\000\372ǧ\367\377\177\000"

print item1.name 
"Xenon\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"

This may be cumbersome, but I will include a printf result from C. 
This result simultaneously looks at parallel chars; that is,
from i=0 to i<16, it looks at item1.name[i] and name[i].

```
// Output is i, item1.name[i], name[i]
each: i is 0,X,X
each: i is 1,e,e
each: i is 2,n,n
each: i is 3,o,o
each: i is 4,n,n
each: i is 5,,
each: i is 6,,
each: i is 7,,
each: i is 8,,▒
each: i is 9,,G
each: i is 10,,▒
each: i is 11,,▒
each: i is 12,,A
each: i is 13,
each: i is 14,,
each: i is 15,,
```

Clearly these two strings are not the same. 
The string from user input has some gibberish inside of it, 
while item1.name's string looks fairly "clean".

I am not sure of what the issue is. 
My logic is that, although name[16] is not in the memory that I reserved, 
if we place '\0' following name[15], then if we do hit '\0' when iterating over name 
we will still run into that memory location, for 15 and 16 are adjacent in memory. 
I do not think this is the issue.

Furthermore, when I set the attribute "name" of item1, it implicitly adds '\0' to my knowledge, 
for we are assigning a string "", not a char '', to the array char name[16]. C abstracts this.

With that said, once again, I am not completely sure what the issue is.

Comment: Gdb shows you the full value of the 16 chars of `name`. That is, including nulls. Would you use `printf` to print it, anything after the null (including the null) will not be printed.

Comment: this is result of printf: item's name: Xenon, input name: Xenon

Comment: You have *nearly*, but not quite, a [mre] there.  Please go the rest of the way.  Supposing that what you have presented is an accurate representation of what the real program is doing, my first guess would be that you are interpreting the return value of `strcmp` incorrectly, but what you've presented does not allow me to do more than speculate.

Comment: The issue is fixed. I should have slept.....I did not set the comparison equal to 0. I am not sure this post will be userful to future people, so I am not sure what to do with it. @JohnBollinger

Comment: Strings end with the terminating `\0`. The `strcpy()` function copies _strings_ so any characters found later in the `item1.name[]` _array_ have indeterminate value (have not been initialized or assigned).

Comment: I see. This is a product of pushing the string into 'item1.name[]' char array, and strcpy handles these non-initialized locations in this manner. Thank you! @exnihilo

Comment: @MichaelRamage -- `strcpy()` reads from a source string until `\0` is encountered; it doesn't handle any following locations in the destination string at all. The arrays `item1.name[]` and `name[]` in the posted code are different arrays, both uninitialized. It should come as no surprise that unmodified locations in those arrays differ.

Comment: Yes. It is no surprise. However, I first thought the reason the comparison was invalidated was due to these differences. I read the gdb output incorrectly as well. @exnihilo

Comment: `name[16] = '\0';` is accessing outside the array. The valid indexes of name are 0 through 15.

Comment: If you want to initialize a string, use `char name[16] = {0};`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I overlooked the fact that I left out " == 0" when performing the comparison with "strcmp(a,b)". Sleep is important. That is all this post teaches. Thanks to all who looked for an issue that I did NOT state in the first edition. Apologies.

Comment: I still question the additional "jibberish" attached in the printf output, however.